# Angular 5 - Service Not Updating Subscribed Variable

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular5, angularfire2, angular-observable

I'm pretty new to Angular..

I have a AuthService in my web app that authenticate users via Angularfire2 (firebase) and insert the email and a flag (indicating whether user filled the profile data form) into a firebase database.

My route guard checks whether the user is authenticated and whether user filled in the the profile data form if not, i redirect to the profile data form. If the user already completed the form, i re direct to hope page.

I obtain whether the user completed the basic data form via **UserData service:**

```
  constructor(private afd: AngularFireDatabase, private authService: AuthService) {

  }

  isProfileComplete (): Observable<any> {
    return this.afd.list(`/users/${this.authService.uid}`)
            .snapshotChanges()

  }
```

Then in the **authGuard** i do the logic to direct the user:

```
 constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router,
              private usrData: UserDataService) {}

  canActivate( route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated())  {
      console.log(this.usrData.isProfileComplete())
      this.usrData.isProfileComplete()
      .map(userInfos => {
        console.log(userInfos)
           userInfos.forEach(item => {
            console.log(userInfos)
            if ((item.payload.key === 'profileComplete') && (item.payload.val() === true)) {
              console.log('user is logged in & data form completed')
              return true;
            } else if ((item.payload.key === 'profileComplete') && (item.payload.val() !== true)) {
              this.router.navigate(['data_form']);
              console.log('user logged in not completed the form')
              return false;
            }
      })

      })

    }  else {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        console.log('user is not logged in ')
        return false;
    }
}
```

I think the code is not reaching the **map** section of the **observable** to read the values for the key **profileComplete**

Could someone kindly point me at the right direction please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following return an Observable?

```
this.usrData.isProfileComplete()
```

Regardless, you're returning true / false from within the context of your forEach loop, which means the outer map method isn't returning anything.

You might want to consider using a `find` rather than a forEach, then you can return the result of whether the `find` found anything:

```
return !!userInfos.find(item => (item.payload.key === 'profileComplete') 
                                && (item.payload.val() === true));
```

Obviously this doesn't handle you redirection case where you want to head back to the form, but should point you in the right direction

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for the response. Unfortunately it looks like the code isn't reaching the item (!!userInfos.find(item => ) when running. i added a console.log just above the return and there was no output.

re:this.usrData.isProfileComplete() yes it returns a  Observable<any> i have added the code bend it above too.

Comment: you also need the return keyword on your map statement.

Comment: perfect, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should return this type `Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>` from `CanActivate`. Because JavaScript not wait callbacks. Example:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
  console.log(this.usrData.isProfileComplete())
  return this.usrData.isProfileComplete()
    .map(userInfos => {
      console.log(userInfos)
      userInfos.forEach(item => {
        console.log(userInfos)
        if ((item.payload.key === 'profileComplete') && (item.payload.val() === true)) {
          console.log('user is logged in & data form completed')
          return of(true);
        } else if ((item.payload.key === 'profileComplete') && (item.payload.val() !== true)) {
          this.router.navigate(['data_form']);
          console.log('user logged in not completed the form')
          return of(false);
        }
      })

    })

} else {
  this.router.navigate(['login']);
  console.log('user is not logged in ')
  return of(false);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Abylay, i made the change you suggested and unfortunately, still the same result.

Comment: I meant to return the Observable, the example was a clue. I see you've found a solution, great!